# Changed frequency of ticks in Pandas '.bar' plot, but messed up the actual bars

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

how's your self-isolation going on?

Mine rocks, as I'm drilling through visualization in Python. Recently, however, I've ran into an issue.

I figured that `.plot.bar()` in Pandas has an uncommon formatting of x-axis (which kinda confirms that I read before I ask). I had price data with monthly frequency, so I applied a fix to display only yearly ticks in a bar chart:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(btc_returns.index, btc_returns)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

Where `btc_returns` is a Series object with datetime in index.

The output I got was weird. Here are the screenshots of what I expected vs the end result.

[image: What I wanted]

[image: What I got]

I tried to find a solution to this, but no luck. Can you guys please give me a hand? Thanks! Criticism is welcome as always :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using the stock value data from [Yahoo Finance: Bitcoin USD](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?period1=1410825600&period2=1587772800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d)
- Technically, you can do `pd.to_datetime(btc.Date).dt.date` at the beginning, but `resample` won't work, which is why `btc_monthly.index.date` is done as a second step.
- `resample` can happen over different periods (e.g. `2M` = every two months)

### Load and transform the data

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
btc = pd.read_csv('data/BTC-USD.csv')

# Date to datetime
btc.Date = pd.to_datetime(btc.Date)

# calculate daily return %
btc['return'] = ((btc.Close - btc.Close.shift(1))/btc.Close.shift(1))*100

# resample to monthly and aggregate by sum
btc_monthly = btc.resample('M', on='Date').sum()

# set the index to be date only (no time)
btc_monthly.index = btc_monthly.index.date
```

### Plot

```py
btc_monthly.plot(y='return', kind='bar', figsize=(15, 8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Plot Bimonthly

```py
btc_monthly = btc.resample('2M', on='Date').sum()  # instead of 'M'
btc_monthly.index = btc_monthly.index.date

btc_monthly.plot(y='return', kind='bar', figsize=(15, 8), legend=False)
plt.title('Bitcoin USD: Bimonthly % Return')
plt.ylabel('% return')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And my solution is like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
ax.bar(btc_returns.index, btc_returns.returns.values, width = 1)
```

Where `btc_returns` is a DataFrame with the returns of BTC. I figured that `.values` makes the bar plot read the datetime input correctly. For the 'missing' bars - their resolution was just way too small, so I set the `width` to '1'.

[image]